# Transposing and Manipulating Data in R

Tags: r

I have the following set of data I would like to transpose.

[image]

I understand that i can use `t(data)` to transpose x y - y x dataframe but how can i transpose the data so that the date is the first row ?

Comment: Never post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: Note that you'll probably need something like `na.locf` from the zoo-package to get your date-column in the proper format.